# Characteristic polynomial and determinant of block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials, block-matrices, characteristic-polynomial

If the square matrix $A$ is invertible,

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}A&B \\ C&D\end{bmatrix} = \det(A) \det\left(D-CA^{-1}B\right)$$

Using this formula, can we come up with the characteristic polynomial of the block matrix using the characteristic polynomial of $A$? Like, can we say that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is always a factor of the characteristic polynomial of the block matrix? If not, then, can we at least say that the characteristic polynomials of $A$ and the block matrix share some roots?
Any hints?

Comment: *"Like, can we say that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is always a factor of the characteristic polynomial of the block matrix?"* Of course not. Consider any square matrix $A$, it would mean that if $a_{11}\ne0$, it's an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: To follow up on Jean-Claude Arbaut's comment: Let $M$ be the block matrix. Then the characteristic polynomial is $\det(M - \lambda I)$, which means in the block matrix, the $A$ and $D$ blocks will become $A - \lambda I$ and $D - \lambda I$. The right determinant will become $\det( D - \lambda I - C (A - \lambda I)^{-1} B)$, and the entries of $(A - \lambda I)^{-1}$ will not be polynomials (there will be $\lambda$'s in the denominator). So applying this formula to a characteristic polynomial factors it as a polynomial times a rational function (not a product of two polynomials).

Comment: It would be nice if $C = O$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Then the characteristic poly will be the product of characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $C$. However, in case $A$ and $C$ commute, then I think we can find the characteristic poly somewhat easily than the direct method

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments of @Nick, the described formula is insufficient to give a formula for the characteristic polynomial, because the term $\det(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is not a polynomial, rather a rational function of $\lambda$. Therefore, the formula for determinant gives a rational function decomposition of the characteristic polynomial, and not a polynomial factorization.